# Java DRY without leaking functions

Tags: java, dry

Suppose I have several classes that are "weak singletons" - things that shouldn't be initialized more than once (registering listeners, etc.), but for whatever reason I can't make them real singletons or even static classes, so the best I can do is warn myself (or throw a `RuntimeException` I guess, but for this question's purposes it doesn't matter how I handle it).

```java
public class WidgetManager {
    private static boolean initialized = false;

    // stuff to be initialized only once

    public WidgetManager() {
        if (initialized) Main.LOGGER.warn("Instantiating multiple instances of " + getClass().getName() + "!");

        // initialize stuff

        initialized = true;
    }
}
```

There are several of these "weak singletons", so typing them by hand gets tiring. Plus it also feels like there should be a better way to do my checks, so as not to repeat myself.

```java
public class FooWidget {
    private static boolean initialized = false;

    // stuff

    public FooWidget() {
        if (initialized) // ...
        // ...
    }
}

public class BarWidget {
    // this gets tiring
}
```

Private functions in interfaces don't work - `private` makes the functions in it only available within the interface definition.

```java
public interface WeakSingleton {
    private void warnReinitialization(boolean initialized) {
        if (initialized) Main.LOGGER.warn("...");
    }
}

public class WidgetManager implements WeakSingleton {
    private static boolean initialized = false;

    public WidgetManager() {
        warnReinitialization(initialized); // <-- Error, function not visible

        initialized = true;
    }
}
```

`default` works, but it exposes it everywhere.

```java
public interface WeakSingleton {
    default void warnReinitialization(boolean initialized) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class WidgetManager implements WeakSingleton {
    private static boolean initialized = false;

    public WidgetManager() {
        warnReinitialization(initialized); // <-- Works here

        initialized = true;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WidgetManager().warnReinitialization(); // <-- Oops, the interface "leaked" ...
    }
}
```

On the surface an abstract class saved me defining the boolean and checking it:

```java
public abstract class WeakSingleton {
    protected static boolean initialized = false;

    protected void warnReinitialization() {
        if (initialized) System.out.println("Warning: Reinitializing " + getClass().getName() + "!");
    }
}

public class WidgetManager extends WeakSingleton {
    private FooWidget foo;
    private BarWidget bar;

    public WidgetManager() {
        warnReinitialization();
        
        System.out.println("WidgetManager ctor");

        initialized = true;
    }
}

public class FooWidget extends WeakSingleton {
    public FooWidget() {
        warnReinitialization();

        System.out.println("FooWidget ctor");

        initialized = true;
    }
}

public class BarWidget extends WeakSingleton {
    public BarWidget() {
        warnReinitialization();

        System.out.println("BarWidget ctor");

        foo = new FooWidget();
        bar = new BarWidget();

        initialized = true;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WidgetManager();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it breaks in other ways:

```
user@host:~ $ javac *
user@host:~ $ java Main
WidgetManager ctor
FooWidget ctor
Warning: Reinitializing BarWidget!
BarWidget ctor
user@host:~ $
```

Questionable design aside, is there a way to achieve my goals of reducing the amount of typing I need for my check without leaking the checking function?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Frame challenge - You don't need to check this inside the object. Simply make sure that your initialization code (for example a DI framework) only gives you a single instance of each object. Most DI frameworks allow you to bind something as singleton.

Comment: @Jorn I suppose I should mention this is a simplified example of the problem I have in my actual project, which is a Minecraft mod. I'm not sure what, if any DI framework I can use in that context - thus my manual handling of everything.

Comment: In addition to what @Jorn said, if you don't want to integrate a whole DI framework, you can also use the factory pattern to centralize the logic to provide a singleton object of the class in question. Using a factory also avoids duplication along different classes.

Comment: Your check doesn't work in a multithreaded environment (trivially imagine 2 threads `new X()` at the same time. They both do not warn, then they both set `initialized = true`. A trivial fix is to use an `AtomicBoolean` for `initialized`, and warn at the end (try to set `initialized` to `true`. If it already ways, emit a warning).

Comment: @rzwitserloot As you only ever set the flag to true, `volatile` also works here.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I don't think I need to handle that in the context of my actual project (Minecraft mod), since I can rely on someone else (the mod loader) to not do that.

Comment: In your abstract class approach, instead of using a single variable you could use a `Set<Class<?>>` and put the classes you've already initialized in there. I do agree with the other comments though: it might be preferable to let a factory handle this logic if your code allows for that.

Comment: The DI framework was just an example. You can achieve the same thing with manually written code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make the constructor `private`, the class `final` and create exactly one instance:

```
public final class WidgetManager {
    public static final WidgetManager INSTANCE = new WidgetManager();

    private WidgetManager() {
    }
}
```

But I don't think you need to have singletons for listeners, just create a new instance each time, even if nothing about the instances is different.

Comment: This won't work if your singleton needs dependencies of its own

Comment: @Jorn Do you mean circular references?

Comment: Not necessarily, any dependencies will do. Because those won't be available when you initialize the class (and thus the `INSTANCE`).

Comment: @Jorn If the class that is being initialized has dependencies, but doesn't know what these dependencies are at compile time, you probably shouldn't use a singleton pattern.

Comment: @Jorn If WidgetManager knows what it depends on at compile time, for example FooWidget and BarWidget, it can simply reference their INSTANCE fields and the class loader will load them first and then WidgetManager. I may not be understanding you correctly.

Comment: `WidgetManager` does indeed know exactly what it needs at compile time, I can reference all the `*Widget` `INSTANCE`s in its private constructor. Despite the downvotes, this answer helped push me in the right direction, thank you for that.